# Guzzle HTTP in laravel API call not returning the expected response

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, guzzle

I'm attempting a GET request to acquire an email_token with Guzzle HTTP that looks like this:

```
$email = $customer['attributes']['Email'];

    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.example.com/apps/api/Services/Email/Opting', [
        'email' => $email
    ]);
    dd($res->getBody());
```

The response is returning 200/OK, but I'm not getting the email_token as expected. The sparse API docs I'm working off give a very similar example and state the expected response's content should look something like this:

```
{
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "marketing": true,
    "promotional": true,
    "news": true,
    "feedback": true,
    "account_related": true,
    "token": "eyJpdiI6Ik9tNlFwbEorbjNnK1FsNnFZb1ZtaFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibGNheWpDR0Z6eWpcL1VCbjdsUXZCS0lzRURBZTIzMVc5ZXRTamQrd1dQTFE9IiwibWFjIjoiYTEwYTM2ODU0MmQzMTY5NGIwNWFhOWFjM2ZiZTBkMzkzOWMyY2VkYTMzNjk5ZDYyOTE0OGY2YjBhNGNkYjk4NyJ9"
}
```

Once I get the token, I then need to make a POST with a couple more requirements (one being the email_token) in order to automate a customer's ability to opt out of the mailing list. Any thoughts on why my response is coming back like this?

[Screenshot of dd($res);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1wh7.png)

[Screenshot of dd($res->getBody());](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jqRD.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the response payload you should do:

```
$response = $res->getBody()->getContents();
```

To get the status:

```
$responseStatus = $res->getStatusCode();
```

documentation for more:
[Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html#responses)

Comment: That's returning HTML, but it looks like there might be an email_token in a meta tag: `<meta name="csrf-token" content="DfGukea4gUxbUWdAhkz3tnb6AFVmcwG3yv0EF22D">`?

Comment: hmm what if you dd $res->getHeaders();

Comment: That looks like this: array:10 [▼
  "Date" => array:1 [▶]
  "Server" => array:1 [▶]
  "X-Powered-By" => array:1 [▶]
  "Cache-Control" => array:1 [▶]
  "X-Mod-Pagespeed" => array:1 [▶]
  "Vary" => array:1 [▶]
  "Content-Length" => array:1 [▶]
  "Content-Type" => array:1 [▶]
  "Set-Cookie" => array:2 [▶]
  "Connection" => array:1 [▶]
]

Comment: there is no token in the headers what if you try dd(json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);

Comment: Yeah, tried that and it's null. Perhaps it's the API?

Comment: null, that indicates that there is something wrong with the api json response! And its odd to return HTML, check your url .

Comment: try to add this to client `$client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]); `before firing the call, since it seems that the api u are sending the request doesn't know that you are making an api call, it thinks that its being accesed from browser! thats why u get HTML back.

Comment: Huh. Ok. The url is super clear in the docs and I just copied and pasted it in.

Comment: That gives me: `Client error: `GET https://www.example.com/apps/api/Services/Email/Opting` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"error":"Unauthenticated."}` when I dd($res->getBody()->getContents());. I had wondered about that. In this method, I brought in the authenticated customer `$customer = Auth::user();`. Do I need to add that to GET request somehow? I'm pulling the email from that authenticated $customer...

Comment: now thats a propper response from an api, and not html.  What kind of authentication api requires ? This is basic auth in guzzle `$response = $client->get('http://www.server.com/endpoint', [
    'auth' => [
        'username', 
        'password'
    ]
]);`  so you need to provide username or email and password!

Comment: Ah. Cool. Not totally sure what it requires. All of the other methods deal with the internal api, so they're just bringing in the basic auth like so: `$customer = Auth::user();` There isn't a username.

Comment: try `$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.example.com/apps/api/Services/Email/Opting', [
       'auth' = [  'email' => $email ] 
    ]);`

Comment: Alright, I have access to password and email, but it's still returning 401 when I try this: ```$customer = Auth::user();
        $email = $customer['attributes']['Email'];
        $password = $customer->getPortalPasswordAttribute();

        $client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]);

        $response = $client->get('https://www.example.com/apps/api/Services/Email/Opting', [ 'auth' => [ $email, $password ] ]);

        $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.example.com/apps/api/Services/Email/Opting', [
            'email' => $email
        ]);```

Comment: ```$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.example.com/apps/api/Services/Email/Opting', [ 'auth' = [ 'email' => $email ] ]);``` returns ErrorException: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: There's a note in the API docs that "Must be authenticated via bearer token."

Comment: haha very important note tho! Do you have a token ? if so `$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,        
    'Accept'        => 'application/json',
];`  add it like this, if not then proppably the api requires to send user and user secret to issue a token for you ! Give me ur slack email for more.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, I don't see a bearer token anywhere else in the app. The api docs don't mention user or user secret to get a token just that the only requirement to get an email_token is an email. Obviously this is not the case. My slack email is matt.a.larson@gmail.com.